# How to print the specific table column using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to print the specific table column.
For example this is the table:

```
|  Name  |  Address |  Contact  |  Add  | Edit | Delete |
|    jj  |     ddd  |  1234564  |   +   |   -  |   x    |
```

The desired scenario here is when I click the print button, the name, address and contact should only be viewed in the print preview.

```
|  Name  |  Address |  Contact  |
|    jj  |     ddd  |  1234564  |
```

Now the problem is the add, edit and delete columns are include in the print preview so how do I remove them. I tried but it doesn't work.

Here's the code for Jquery print:

```
$('.print_stud').click(function() {
        w=window.open();    
        w.document.write('<html><head><title>Requested Medicines</title></head><body><center><h2>Requested Medicines</h2></center>') + '</body></html>';
        w.document.write($('.p').html()); //to be printed
        w.print();
        w.close();  
});
```

Here's the code for displaying the data in php and html. This data will be used for print preview:

```
<?php 

    echo "<div class='p'>"; //the area to be printed

    while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $test['id'];
?>
    <tr>    
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['p_name'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['date'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['product_name'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['drug_name'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'>&#8369;<?php echo number_format($test['s_price'], 2); ?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['quantity'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'>&#8369;<?php echo number_format($test['sold'], 2); ?></font></td>

    <?php echo "<div class='p'>"; //The last area to be printed. The delete column should not be included ?>            

        <td><center><a href ='del.php?&opr=delRequest&id=<?php echo $test['id'];?>' title="Delete"><span style="font-size:1.4em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></center></a> <!--Delete column--->
    </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hide them when previewing.

Comment: U can hide those columns through css apply display:none to those columns when previewing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick Solution:

Try using a CSS3 Print Stylesheet: https://jsfiddle.net/jgdapgcx/1/

**Edit:**

OP is using jQuery to open the window, so here's how to open the window *and* have this solution:

```
$('.print_stud').click(function() {
        w=window.open();    
        w.document.write('<html><head><style>@media print{.dontprint{display:none;}}</style><title>Requested Medicines</title></head><body><center><h2>Requested Medicines</h2></center>') + '</body></html>';
        w.document.write($('.p').html()); //to be printed
        w.print();
        w.close();  
});
```

(Note the `<style>@media print{.dontprint{display:none;}}</style>` on line 3).

Then all you need to do is add the class to the delete column and you should be good to go :D

### How it works:

`@media` rules are only enacted by CSS when they fit a certain media condition. This can be used for responsive website design (change CSS rules on screen size), but also to change the design of a page for print media.

Any rules inside `@media print {}` (between the curly brackets) are enacted **only** when the document is being printed.

Here's how it works in your case:

- We first give the delete column a unique class. It doesn't matter what this is. In this example, I'm using `dontprint` like so:

  ```
  ...<td class="dontprint"><center>...
  ```
- We add a `@media print` set to our CSS file:

  ```
  @media print {

  }
  ```
- Inside the curly brackets, we select the column with a class of `dontprint`. This selects that element to apply a certain set of styles to it only when we are printing:

  ```
  @media print {
      .dontprint {

      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, we add the `display:none` rule to `.dontprint`. This means that it will not be displayed while the document is printing:

  ```
  @media print {
      .dontprint {
          display:none;
      }
  }
  ```

You can try this in the Fiddle by trying to print it. Although you will see a bit of the JSFiddle interface, you will also note that the final table row is not displayed in the Print Preview.

### Other Information:

- [Browser Support Charts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) for `@media`

Comment: It works when I click the ctrl + p. How will it work using jQuery?

Comment: @HelpMe jQuery isn't involved in this solution - it's pure CSS I know that you're opening the window with jQuery, so I'll edit and show you what you need to do to make it work when the window is opened.

Comment: Yes it works. I never thought that the css style can be applied in the  `w.document.write('');` :). Your solution makes me happy.

Comment: Glad I could help :D

Comment: Sir I tried to change the margin but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the table, manipulate rows on clone and then convert to html string

```
var $tableClone = $('#tableId').clone();
$tableClone.find('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:gt(2)').remove();
});
var tableHtml = $tableClone[0].outerHTML;
```

Note that tags `<center>` and `<font>` are deprecated in html5. Use css instead

Answer (score -1):

You can add class hide to all element must hide from print and use this code

```
    $(".printprint_stud").click(function(){
    $('.hide').hide();
    window.print();
    $('.hide').show();
});
```

or use @media css